# Personal git branch

Tags: git, github

I would like to make a branch of a project on github that has my own modifications specific to my situation. I also want to sync this branch between my home, work and travel laptop computers. And finally I want my branch to still receive updates that the primary developer makes to the root project.

I've only ever used git to clone to my local machine to build them, so I'm not too familiar with the rest of it's functionality. I'm using git 2.7.4 on Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Read the git book, which is free. It explains forking, branching, merging, rebasing.

Comment: The major challenge here is that whatever someone would tell you to do to accomplish what you want would just bring up more questions. The only way for you to do this correctly would be to learn git, there really is no other simple way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by this...

If you create a branch of someone else's repo, then you can commit, push, and pull from that branch without touching the master branch.

If this isn't the answer you're looking for, maybe look into GitLab? You just need to install it on a personal server of yours and then you basically have a private and completely customizable GitHub.

Comment: Mostly. So once I have my own branch and the main branch is modified, like a bug fix for example. Can I incorporate that bug fix into my branch without overwriting the changes I've made?

Comment: Yes, you can always pull changes from the master branch. You can even push changes to the master branch, but in your case you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

git repository forking is what you are looking for. You can have a fork of  a particular repository. This fork is your own copy and you can do what ever you want (personal). Also you can sync your repository with the original repository.

See following article for more info
https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/